# How do I open an image from a Collection View in its own Image View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am making an application in which I am saving images in a database with their details. I used a Collection View to show the images and now i want to be able to click on one and show it on a new page in an Image View so that I can provide details for that image and save them in the database.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this, i would say if you are using storyboard, smily make another view controller with ImageView, and make a push segue from CollectionViewCell to the new created ViewCOntroller and finally, you will have to use something like this "Example Code"

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]]) {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"??"]) {
            if ([segue.destinationViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setImage:)]) {
                [segue.destinationViewController performSelector:@selector(setImage:)
                                                      withObject:YOUR CELL IMAGE];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to put Push Segue Identifier or else, it won't work.

Comment: how can i keep swipe-left / right to select next/previous image on the anther view? can i reuse current collection view items on this new view?

Answer (score 2):

You should implement following method of UICollectionViewDelegate:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
     //retrieve image from your array
     //push new view controller/perform segue with image
}
```